# Soma dos quadrados

Tags: c

Eu estive a fazer uma função para calcular a soma do primeiro numero (x0) com a razão (r) multiplicando por um numero (n) de vezes, como esta função:

```
double sum_arithmetic(double x0, double r, int n)
{
   return n == 0 ? 0 : x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1);
}
```

por exemplo quando x0=6, r=3, n=3 o resultado é 27 porque é 6 + 9 + 12, mas agora quero o mesmo tipo de função para a soma dos quadrados, para calcular a soma x^2 + (x+1)^2 + … + (x+n-1)^2 , para x e n dados, mas não estou a conseguir como chegar a essa função :/

Comment: Não sei se interpretei direito sua questão, mas se o problema é calcular o quadrado, `x²` é a equivalente a `x*x`. Se quiser manter a forma recursiva basta substituir `x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1);` por `x0 * x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n-1);`

Comment: muito obrigado, era mesmo isso!

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues +1 pelo problema, legal ver esses problemas que envolvem p.a

Answer (score 2):

Essa é uma função recursiva que calcula a soma da progressão aritmética termo a termo (`x`, `x + r`, `x + 2r`, etc). A soma dos quadrados segue a mesma estrutura, a única diferença é que em cada passo recursivo deverá ser computado **x²** (`x0 * x0`).

```
double sumOfSquares(double x0, double r, int n)
{
   return n == 0 ? 0 : x0 * x0 + sumOfSquares(x0 + r, r, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar sem recursão, pois o tempo computacional será bem menor, abaixo está implementado de forma iterativa:

```
double quadrado(double x0, double r, int n)
{
   int resultado = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<n ;i++)
    {
         resultado = resultado + (x0+r*i)*(x0+r*i);  
    }
   return resultado;
```

}

A implementação iterativa geralmente tende a ser ligeiramente mais rápida na prática do que a implementação recursiva, uma vez que uma implementação recursiva precisa registrar o estado atual do processamento de maneira que ela possa continuar de onde parou após a conclusão de cada nova execução subordinada do procedimento recursivo. Esta ação consome tempo e memória.

Outra possível motivação para se escolher um algoritmo iterativo ao invés de um algoritmo recursivo é que nas linguagens de programação modernas o espaço disponível para o fluxo de controle é geralmente bem menor que o espaço disponível no heap, e algoritmos recursivos tendem a necessitar de mais espaço na pilha do que algoritmos iterativos.

É importante mencionar que está solução iterativa requer duas variáveis temporárias(contando com i) e mesmo assim gastará tempo de execução inferior ao recursivo; em geral, formulações recursivas de algoritmos são freqüentemente consideradas "mais enxutas" ou "mais elegantes" do que formulações iterativas.